Valkey Cache in C#
I am trying to use Valkey with the IDistributedCache interface in C#. I have pulled the Valkey container using docker pull valkey/valkey and I am running it on the default port 6379. However, there are zero nuget packages for Valkey.
So I used the latest Redis packages Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis 8.0.5 and StackExchange.Redis 2.7.33, but I always get this error when trying to save something to the cache. Did I misconfigure the connection to the container or are the nuget packages really incompatible? And if it is the latter, is there any library for using Valkey in C#?
Thank you for your help!
The message timed out in the backlog attempting to send because no connection became available (5000ms) - Last Connection Exception: 
It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). ConnectTimeout, command=EVAL, timeout: 5000, inst: 0, qu: 1, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: 
SpinningDown, rs: NotStarted, ws: Idle, in: 0, last-in: 0, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 1, async-ops: 0, serverEndpoint: localhost:6379, conn-sec: n/a, 
aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: MY-CLIENT-NAME(SE.Redis-v2.7.33.41805), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), 
WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=16,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=8,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=268,Timers=6), v: 2.7.33.41805 
(Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)


Hi; it is anticipated that Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis and StackExchange.Redis should (in due course) work with all common RESP implementations; support for Garnet was added in .NET 9 Preview 4 (due any day), for example; I will take a moment to try Valkey and see what is breaking (for context: I'm both the SE.Redis person and the MSFT distributed caching person)

BTW I got this working fine with docker using docker run -it --expose 6379 -p 6379:6379 valkey/valkey

Short version: I suspect this is a container networking / forwarding setup issue, or in the more general case: firewall or DNS; suggestion: use redis-cli (or valkey-cli, or garnet-cli, etc) to connect to the server from your intended client node (probably your application server), and see if it can connect. redis-cli ping is always a good start.

Long version (using naked OS for server):
A quick test showed it working fine; server:
marc@mgx:~/valkey/src$ ./valkey-server
... snip
                .+^+.
            .+#########+.
        .+########+########+.           Valkey 255.255.255 (9b6232b5/0) 64 bit
    .+########+'     '+########+.
 .########+'     .+.     '+########.    Running in standalone mode
 |####+'     .+#######+.     '+####|    Port: 6379
 |###|   .+###############+.   |###|    PID: 11402
 |###|   |#####*'' ''*#####|   |###|
 |###|   |####'  .-.  '####|   |###|
 |###|   |###(  (@@@)  )###|   |###|          https://valkey.io
 |###|   |####.  '-'  .####|   |###|
 |###|   |#####*.   .*#####|   |###|
 |###|   '+#####|   |#####+'   |###|
 |####+.     +##|   |#+'     .+####|
 '#######+   |##|        .+########'
    '+###|   |##|    .+########+'
        '|   |####+########+'
             +#########+'
                '+v+'

11402:M 17 May 2024 10:04:26.095 * Server initialized
11402:M 17 May 2024 10:04:26.095 * Loading RDB produced by valkey version 255.255.255
11402:M 17 May 2024 10:04:26.095 * RDB age 82 seconds
11402:M 17 May 2024 10:04:26.095 * RDB memory usage when created 1.64 Mb
11402:M 17 May 2024 10:04:26.095 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 41, keys expired: 0.
11402:M 17 May 2024 10:04:26.096 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
11402:M 17 May 2024 10:04:26.096 * Ready to accept connections tcp

test connection:
➜ .\redis-cli.exe info server
# Server
redis_version:7.2.4
server_name:valkey
valkey_version:255.255.255
...snip

test setup:
        svc.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
        {
            options.Configuration = "127.0.0.1:6379";
        });

those tests fail if I kill the server, but with it running:
➜ dotnet test
Restore complete (0.6s)
.... snip
Test summary: total: 292, failed: 0, succeeded: 292, skipped: 0, duration: 7.1s
Build succeeded in 8.6s

Basically: it looks fine to me! Note I'm using the .NET 9 dev branch, but I don't think that should matter here - or rather, if that was a factor, I'd expect to see RedisServerException complaining about unknown commands, rather than a connection error.

It seems that it was indeed a port forwarding issue. I mapped the internal port 6379 to another port in the docker run command and now it works fine. Thanks a lot for your quick response! :)

@devbert_5095960 thanks (genuinely) for making me actually take the time to validate it rather than just assuming it would work fine; I mean... it does, but I should have tested it anyway ;p
